# On Button click pop up is opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, dialog

I have a scenario where I want to validate a `textbox` on `button` click. What I want is

I have a `textbox` and `button` if user doesnt enter any value in the textbox and click on button it should prompt a message as enter the details. Its happening till here.

But at the same time the pop up is also opening even if the user has not enter any details. SO I want it to stop. Below is my code which I tried.

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="txtStoreCode" />
<input type="button" value="View Details" id="viewDetails" class="headButt" onclick="getStoreInfo();" />
```

Pop Up which is opening.

```
$('#viewDetails').on('click', function() {
    $("#storeCodeDialog").dialog({
        width: 'auto',

    });

    $("div[aria-describedby='storeCodeDialog'] .ui-dialog-title").text('3328');

    $('div[aria-describedby="storeCodeDialog"]').css({
        'left': '18px',
        'top': '103px'
    });

});
```

And my function to validate is below

```
var STORE_ID = $('#txtStoreCode').val();
if (STORE_ID == "" || STORE_ID == null) {
    jAlert('Kindly enter Store Id', 'INFORMATION');
    $('#storeCodeDialog').hide();
    return false;
}
```

I tried with `hide()` but still the pop up is opening how to stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your popup is attached to click event if `#viewDetails`. To prevent that popup, validate first that input is not empty then write popup's code.

e.g.

```
function getStoreInfo() {
    var STORE_ID = $('#txtStoreCode').val();

    if (STORE_ID == "" || STORE_ID == null) {
        jAlert('Kindly enter Store Id', 'INFORMATION');
        $('#storeCodeDialog').hide();
        return false;
    }
    // This will execute if store id is not empty.
    $("#storeCodeDialog").dialog({
        width: 'auto',
    });

    $("div[aria-describedby='storeCodeDialog'] .ui-dialog-title").text('3328');

    $('div[aria-describedby="storeCodeDialog"]').css({
        'left': '18px',
        'top': '103px'
    });

}
```

And remove click handler.

Comment: thanks for immediate reply, which click handler you are talking about

Comment: `$('#viewDetails').on('click'...` remove this code. As we have included it in `getStoreInfo` function.

Comment: oh ok. let me try and check.

Comment: Pleasure. If that helped, mark answer as solved and you can upvote also ;)

Comment: sure.I will. but I only can after 3 mins. you know stack validations are perfect ;)

Comment: Absolutely Perfect :) Thanks btw.

Comment: hi shyam can u help with one more thing here. if you dont mind

Comment: Please update question, or if it's a different issue post new question

Comment: Yes I will post as a new question after some time. Came for lunch now